how to change the default app launcher /splash screen
how can i change the default app launcher screen without using flutter_launcher_icons,
I have tried. flutter_launcher_icons to change the launcher screen, but it's not giving me result as expected. I need a custom animated launcher, or how to disable the default splash screen.

To change the default app launcher (splash screen) in Flutter, you'll need to update the launch screen defined in the native Android (for Android). Here's how you can do it :
First you need to select an image which you want to keep in app launcher/Splash Screen then you need to generate an app icon. I recommend : icon.kitchen Download the zip file and you got five mipmap folder in it
Now in your Flutter project open 'android/app/src/main/res'. You'll see there are already five mipmap folder. You just have to change the folders which we generated.
All set.

You can change your default splash screen but using native code. See below instructions:

For Android: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen.
iOS: As far as I remmember, it is "Launch Screen storyboard": https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/how-to-design-and-add-a-launch-screen-for-your-ios-app-e498eb1203de

Another option, you can create 2 splash screens. The first screen should be default, and the second one you could write them in Flutter/Dart. Many apps use this option.
